# Laravel accessor and relation methods have the same name problem

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

please consider this situation:

```
model name = Workflow
attribute name = current_user (a foreign key to User model)
```

then my relation method is:

```
public function currentUser()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'current_user', 'id');
}
```

and my accessor method is ([according to Laravel 9.x Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)):

```
protected function currentUser(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn($value) => User::find($value)->full_name(),
        set: fn($value) => $value,
    );
}
```

they have the same name, and not working!

also, I tried to change their names but Laravel won't recognize them and returns a `null` object.

*update
I'm using workflows this way and I need each user_full_name instead of user_id, that's why I wrote that accessor!

```
$wf_list = RequestBase::where('request_code', $request->input('request_code'))
            ->firstOrFail()->review->workflow
            ->makeHidden(['next_user', 'office_order', 'created_at'])
            ->append(['receive_date', 'send_date']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution for the accessor method ([on Laravel 8.x Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)):

```
protected function getNextUserAttribute($value)
{
    return User::find($value)->full_name();
}
```

but I'm not sure it's the right way, is it?

Answer (score 0):

I used to use this way

In `User` model

```
protected function getFullNameAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->last_name . ' ' . $this->first_name;
}
```

In `Workflow` modal

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'current_user', 'id');
}
```

```
$workflow = Workflow::with('user')->where('id', //id)->first();
$fullName = $workflow->user->fullName;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily get access to `full_name()` by relation. And you don't need accessor for it.

```
$workflow = Workflow::with('currentUser')->where('id', $id)->first();
$fullName = $workflow->currentUser->full_name();
```

Comment: please check the update

Comment: If you want to apply `eager loading` concept on your query, you can make like this `RequestBase::with(['review.workflow', 'review.workflow.currentUser''])`

Comment: the variable name `$wf_list` gets a RequestBase object `firstOrFail()` and then finds a workflow list through its relation, workflows can be more than one.

Comment: @mjavadtatari OK. Did you solve it or still figuring it out?

Answer (score 0):

and finally found this way to change an attribute in an item in a Laravel collection:

```
$wf_list->map(function ($item) {
        $temp_user = User::find($item->current_user);
        $item->current_user = $temp_user->full_name();
        return $item;
});
```